# Save multiple lists into 1 csv by column?

Tags: list, csv, numpy, export-to-csv

How to save multiple lists into a .csv file with numpy, where each list represents a column.

For example:

```
A=['A','B','C']
B=['1','2','3']
```

The csv output file should look like this

```
A,1
B,2
C,3
```

Tried this but it only takes 1 argument, how to do it?

`numpy.savetxt('output.csv', A,B , delimiter=',', fmt='%s')`

Comment: look at `numpy.hstack`, `vstack`, and `stack`

Comment: `savetxt` saves an array, not lists.  If given a list (or list of lists) it tries to convert it to an array.

Comment: @hpaulj yes but I am working with lists if I convert it into an array then it adds the `{'' ''}` elements too, which is not spreadsheet compatible.

Comment: How about writing the lists directly?  Maybe using zip to iterate on them.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need numpy for this.  It is easy enough to do with the [`csv` Python module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

For example,

```
In [13]: A
Out[13]: ['A', 'B', 'C']

In [14]: B
Out[14]: ['1', '2', '3']

In [15]: import csv

In [16]: with open('AB.csv', 'w') as f:
    ...:     writer = csv.writer(f)
    ...:     writer.writerows(zip(A, B))
    ...: 

In [17]: !cat AB.csv
A,1
B,2
C,3
```

Or just plain Python, without the `csv` module:

```
In [26]: with open('AB.csv', 'w') as f:
    ...:     f.write(''.join('{},{}\n'.format(a, b) for a, b in zip(A, B)))
    ...:     

In [27]: !cat AB.csv
A,1
B,2
C,3
```

But if you really want to use `numpy.savetxt`:

```
In [28]: import numpy as np

In [29]: np.savetxt('AB.csv', list(zip(A, B)), fmt='%s', delimiter=',')

In [30]: !cat AB.csv
A,1
B,2
C,3
```

All of those suggestions use `zip(A, B)` to create a sequence of paired tuples from `A` and `B`:

```
In [34]: list(zip(A, B))
Out[34]: [('A', '1'), ('B', '2'), ('C', '3')]
```